# How to Query Large Sharepoint 2013 Lists in Infopath 2010?

Tags: list, drop-down-menu, sharepoint-2013, infopath2010, data-connections

I'm designing an Infopath form to help guide people in a data creation process. The form needs to draw from a Sharepoint list that contains around 19,000 rows, each with six columns that contain attributes (Column 1 = Attribute A, Column 2 = Attribute B, etc.) I've reduced the first three columns to their own lists, which contain only a few hundred unique entries each, if that. When I get to Column 4, there are 8,000 unique entries, which makes querying the list outright impossible

In an attempt to get around the item limitation, I've created an Infopath form with a data connection to the list (which does not automatically query when the form is loaded). Additionally, I've added drop downs that sets values for the queryFields of the secondary data source (one for Column 1, another for Column 2, and another for Column 3). On the last drop down, I set an action to query the database, but I still get the error regarding limitations and that rules cannot be applied.

Is there any way to "pre-filter" the data connection so that I can bypass the limitation by only drawing the data I need? Am I going about this the right way?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to add indexes to your list columns that you intend to query on? I've found that I can get around the error message on list limits if I go to the list and add an index for the columns that I will be setting as query fields prior to running my query data connection.

Comment: We ended up saving the information to an Excel list for the time being and managing that through other programs that could link directly to the Excel file. Thank you for your input though!